# How to set div between two div

Tags: css

I need to make something like this , how can I make the square on the middle between this two? Here is the CSS and [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxABJ.png)

My Css

```
#up{  
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
   }
#down{  
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
   }
#square{  
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
   }
```

Can I setting the square without counting the percentage of the location of the middle line? (because I want to add all something like this into all sessions of the web , and the height of the session will responsive by the text length

Comment: Upload the html/css so we have something to work with instead of doing everything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use position relative to outer div and position relative to inner div

here is the link how can you do it

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anshul_Sinha/yw5522fz/)

```css
.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.one {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: red;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="square">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="two">

</div>
<div class="three">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `<div>` square as:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

in CSS:

```
#div1{
 border: 1px red;
 height: /*enter the height */
 width: /* enter the width */
 position: relative;
 left: /*enter the distance */
 right: /*enter the distance */
 top: /*enter the distance */
 bottom: /*enter the distance */
 z-index: 100 /* make sure other div's have z index lesser than this div's */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the square INTO the second div, give it a `position: absolute` and a `top: -20px` (and `left: Xpx`- i.e. whatever you need/want).

Answer (score 0):

> You can easily do this with position:absolute to your small box div.

**Here is the solution that can help you**

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0px;
}

#up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
}

#down {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  background: blue;
}

#square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(30% - 20px);
  margin: 0px auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="up"></div>

<div id="down"></div>
<div id="square"></div>
```